# Alternative, more efficient scraping method for a noncoder, than Google doc's importxml and xpath?

Tags: database, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, screen-scraping

I've searched throughout the net for a simple solution, but it seems everyone has their own unique method (coding language) of achieving this. I'm only just beginning to learn Linux, and my coding skills are thoroughly lacking (non-existent). I love the simplicity of using importxml and xpath, but copying and pasting values after reaching the spreadsheet limit of 50 is getting old. Now that I've seen the light, I would really just like to know of a simple, yet scalable solution to get more data into more spreadsheets/databases.

Before I really start getting my hands dirty, I would love to know some of the ways you guys go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I can warmly recommend http://www.scraperwiki.com

You can copy others examples and go a long way without coding skills. There is a mailinglist where you can ask for scrapers and you can hire them to do the scraping.